# A problem with non-exact ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$xy^3dx=(x^2y+2)dy$$
After switching everything to one side
$$xy^3dx-(x^2y+2)dy=0$$
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=3xy^2$$$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=-2xy$$
$\frac1P(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})=\frac{(-3y-2)}{y^2}$ is only dependant on y, so the integrating factor will be $$e^{\int \frac{(-3y-2)}{y^2}} $$
But thats where my problem starts. After evaluating this and multiplying both sides of the equation by it partial derivatives sre not equal so I must have made a mistake somewhere, but Im unable to find it.

Comment: Your integrating factor $e^{\int \frac{(-3y-2)}{y^2}dy} $ is correct. Note that it is equal to $\frac{e^{2/y}}{y^3}$ . You will find the same result than with the other method shown in my answer.

Comment: Hi Lugi ! You wrote : <<After evaluating this and multiplying both sides of the equation by it partial derivatives are not equal so I must have made a mistake somewhere, but Im unable to find it.>>. The partial derivatives are equal. Your mistake is certainly in calculing them. Without having the details of your calculus, it is not possible to see where is the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

$xy^3dx=(x^2y+2)dy$

Hint :

Let $X=x^2$

$y^3=2(Xy+2)\frac{dy}{dX}$

Let $y=-\frac{2}{Y}$

$\frac{dX}{dY}=-X+Y$

This linear ODE leads to $X(Y)$. The inverse function $Y(X)$ involves the Lambert W function.